# reading sent and received SYS and ACK packets with dpkt and python

Tags: python, dpkt

I need to parse a .pcap file to detect possible SYS scans. I need to be able to display the IP address of any IP addresses that sent 3 times as many SYS packets as the number of SYS+ACK packets they received. Now I have a general idea of how to implement this. My issue is that I do not how to get the different SYS packets (how to differentiate from the sent/received packets) when parsing the pcap file. I have looked at other posts, and the [documentation](http://www.commercialventvac.com/dpkt.html#mozTocId147538) but have been unlucky.

I started a python program that starts a bit like this:

```
import dptk

    //take in command line arguement
    file = arg

        openFile = open(file)
        pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(openFile)

    //not sure about these two lines
        syn_flag = ( tcp.flags & dpkt.tcp.TH_SYN ) != 0       
        ack_flag = ( tcp.flags & dpkt.tcp.TH_ACK ) != 0
```

When I call those last two lines, am I getting all SYS and all ACK packets from the pcap? How do I tell which have been sent/received?

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend that you use the Scapy tool that can be found [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/).  Scapy is a packet generation and manipulation tool that gives you a large amount of flexibility to dissect packets.  Following is a quick example of what the Scapy code might look like:

```
pkts = PcapReader(inFile)
for p in pkts:
        F = bin(p['TCP'].flags)
        if F == SYN # 0x02:
            # Process Syn Packet
        elif F == ACK # 0x10:
            # Process Ack Packet
```

Scapy can be used from its interpreter, or you can import the Scapy frame work into your own environment

Comment: Thank you very much. I also looked at scapy. The sample code above is very helpful. I will take a look at it. But I still have the question regarding how I would differentiate between sent/received SYS/ACK packets. @BrianCain

Comment: or is it that SYN is the sent, and SYN+ACK is the received? Sorry I am a bit new to all of this.

Comment: Your best bet may be to start with an understanding of how the Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) works.  I suggest starting with the wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol
The page provides a good visual of the TCP header.  You are particularly interested in the Flags field.